# On Bohr's response to EPR

Tags: soft-question, quantum-interpretations, history, epr-experiment

If I understand correctly, the EPR paper (1935) points out that quantum mechanics is incomplete theory if it describes **individual** particles and measurements. This is true by the mathematical formalism. But already in 1926 quantum mechanics had its statistical interpretation, and in 1930 Heisenberg in his Chicago Lectures admits that position and momentum can be known exactly. So why didn't Bohr just give a short reply: $$\text{"It's a statistical theory."}$$

Comment: From what I understand: because EPR seems to imply something beyond the fact that it's a statistical theory. The EPR construction creates a situation where with certainty you measure a correlation that apparently you "aren't supposed" to have... I think that EPR came as a surprise and as an interesting topic to discuss even to the greatest experts of QM at the time

Comment: @Amit Well, ok. Non-locality was big deal back then.

Comment: It's always a big deal if you can't explain it :) Obviously Einstein was the natural gatekeeper for violations of the speed of causality here... eventually it was explained in the sense that it doesn't imply a violation of causality / transfer of information. But in general you know, Bohr apparently was always willing to engage in a discussion with Einstein, I was very glad to find this page at the time that gives that a kind of an overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Einstein_debates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that would be conceding to Einstein's view. Einstein believed quantum theory is statistical and not fundamental, and the EPR provides an argument for that view. Bohr believed quantum theory is fundamental, and thus did not agree with Einstein's characterization of the theory as incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that Bohr didn't say quantum mechanics is a statistical theory because that claim is false. The square amplitudes of quantum states don't always obey the rules of probability, e.g. - during quantum interference experiments in general break those rules, see Section 2 of

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150

Also, quantum mechanics does provide a complete description of individual quantum systems in terms of their Heisenberg picture observables:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

Comment: Quantum interference experiments do not obey merely rules of probability, there are other rules in addition, like superposition, Schr. equation, etc. The latter rules override uninformed probability calculus in some respect. But this does not mean that the theory can't be viewed as statistical in the sense of statistical physics. Already classical systems of many degrees of freedom obey more rules than just the elementary rules of probability - the equations of motion. But this does not prevent us from using statistical physics to describe these systems.